# python polars: df partition with pivot and concat

Tags: python, python-polars

my goal was to groupby/partition by one column (a below), create a string identifier  (b and c columns) then use this b_c identifier as a name for a column in a pivoted data frame.
Code below works OK as far as I can tell, but the path to get the result is a bit twisted. So my question is: can this be done in a simpler way?
BTW, at this tiny scale (max 1k of rows so far) I am not obsessed to make it faster.

```
data = {
    "a": [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3],
    "b": [11, 12, 13, 11, 12, 11],
    "c": ["x1", "x2", "x3", "x1", "x2", "x1"],
    "val": [101, 102, 102, 201, 202, 301],
}
df = pl.DataFrame(data)

print(df)

counter = 0
for tmp_df in df.partition_by("a"):
    grp_df = (
        tmp_df.with_columns((pl.col("b") + "_" + pl.col("c")).alias("col_id"))
        .drop(["b", "c"])
        .pivot(values="val", index="a", columns="col_id")
    )

    if counter == 0:
        result_df = grp_df.select(pl.all())
    else:
        result_df = pl.concat([result_df, grp_df], how="diagonal")
    counter += 1

print(result_df)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do this in 2 step: first a select step to create the new `id` column, then the pivot.

*Example 1*:

```
(
    df.select(
        'a','val',
        id = pl.col('b').cast(pl.Utf8) + '_' + pl.col('c'))
    .pivot(values='val',index='a', columns='id')
)

# Result
shape: (3, 4)
┌─────┬───────┬───────┬───────┐
│ a   ┆ 11_x1 ┆ 12_x2 ┆ 13_x3 │
│ --- ┆ ---   ┆ ---   ┆ ---   │
│ i64 ┆ i64   ┆ i64   ┆ i64   │
╞═════╪═══════╪═══════╪═══════╡
│ 1   ┆ 101   ┆ 102   ┆ 102   │
│ 2   ┆ 201   ┆ 202   ┆ null  │
│ 3   ┆ 301   ┆ null  ┆ null  │
└─────┴───────┴───────┴───────┘
```

*Example 2*:
(suggested by @jqurious), using pl.format

```
(
    df.select(
        'a','val',
        id = pl.format("{}_{}", "b", "c"))
    .pivot(values='val',index='a', columns='id')
)
```

Comment: Thank you. It is a way nicer way to do it. Your code works with polars '0.16.14' python 3.10.6. I had a problem running it with polars 0.16.16 but it was fluke: some issue with jupyter/PATH probably.

Comment: Hi @darked89 , I tried the code on my machine running Polars 0.16.16 and Python 3.11 and it worked. So my guess is also something unrelated to Polars (like you mention Jupyter or path issue). If it still doesn’t work, please share about it

Comment: Perhaps an example of `pl.format` could also be useful to show: `df.with_columns(pl.format("{}_{}", "b", "c").pivot()`

Comment: nice idea @jqurious . i'll add it